# ReflectionClass of static in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm aware that I cannot have `new ReflectionClass(static)` in PHP (5.3) as I just tried it. Is there any other way to get around this restriction?

Passing in a string is not an option, although somehow getting the string of the class name is acceptable. However, idk if it'd work as I'm working with namespaces as well.

Thanks

Comment: `static` is a keyword, not an object or an class. Why did you expect it to work? What were you intending to do?

Comment: I know I'm not suppose to expect PHP to treat classes and functions as first class citizens.. but I keep hoping.. >.>

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/get_called_class) to get a string containing the called class.

```
class Foo {
  public static function getReflection() {
    return new ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {}

$reflectBar = Bar::getReflection();
// reflectBar now holds a ReflectionClass instance for Bar
```

Comment: Used this for chaining of static methods when they are extended. E.g. `public function method1() { return get_called_class(); }`. Ugly, but works.